# How to return a float not string from a function in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, return

How do you return a float not string from a function in python 2.7?

Comment: What code do you have so far?  Return will give you the type the variable already is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python returns variables in whatever type they happen to be while in the function:

```
def return_something(x):
    print(type(x))
    return x

return_something(1.0)
```

`>>> <type 'float'>`

However, you can tell Python that you want to "cast" data to a certain type:

```
return_something(float(1))
```

`>>> <type 'float'>`

in the latter case, our data was an int, but by calling `float()`, you can modify its type.